# React DND dragging an item from 1 list to another

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I want to be able to drag, rearrange, and move them from 1 list to another. Functionally it currently partially works in that you can drag an item once and it updates but after that you can no longer move the items inside the list.

Example here:

<del>https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dnd-multiple-lists-8z7vs?file=/src/question.tsx</del>

Any hints or pointers would be very helpful.

Thanks

---

I have created a new example here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-perlman-zs3xm?file=/src/Container.tsx

It is simplified, I am now able to drag a component from one section to another. But it seems to bug out when trying to drag from one to another.

Comment: Codesandobx is opening with errors

Comment: Hi thanks for checking this out, it seems to open ok for me. Are you able open and see Codesandbox and drag elements around?